# "Connect timed out" error when initializing a project in IDEA

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea, build

Help with the problem, IDEA has stopped launching projects. I'm trying to initialize the project, that is, add a Java version, but the following error appears. That is, the necessary folders are not built, literally at all.  I'm at a dead end, please tell me what the problems might be.

I tried a bunch of things - changed versions of Java, created a project from the command line (via Gradl) and through the idea, disabled the firewall on Windows, checked all the boxes in it first related to IDEA and java, IDEA was added to the firewall, reinstalled IDEA, did maven project.. no changes. Another point - I can create a project on Windows and it builds and works fine there. stopped at WSL. Although yesterday everything was still ok.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh2M8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAAM5.png)

Logs

```
2024-03-25 19:20:25,677 [1906411]   WARN - #o.j.p.g.s.e.GradleExecutionHelper - Failed to obtain build environment from Gradle daemon.
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not connect to server /172.29.189.138:45279. Tried addresses: [/172.29.189.138].
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.GradleServerRunner$GradleServerEventsListener.start$lambda$1(GradleServerRunner.kt:179)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:249)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextCallable.call(ContextCallable.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:27)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.TargetBuildExecuter.runAndGetResult(TargetBuildExecuter.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.TargetModelBuilder.get(TargetModelBuilder.kt:21)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.getBuildEnvironment(GradleExecutionHelper.java:838)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.getBuildEnvironment(GradleExecutionHelper.java:330)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:209)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:870)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:851)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$0(GradleExecutionHelper.java:145)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.maybeFixSystemProperties(GradleExecutionHelper.java:177)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$1(GradleExecutionHelper.java:145)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService$Companion.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt:233)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:141)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:34)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.executeSync(ExternalSystemUtil.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:325)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemTaskUnderProgress$2.run(ExternalSystemTaskUnderProgress.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsynchronously$5(CoreProgressManager.java:484)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$0(ProgressManager.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:192)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:685)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:641)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:609)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:179)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.runProcess(ProgressManager.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$5(ProgressRunner.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner$ProgressRunnable.run(ProgressRunner.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext$runAsCoroutine$1.invoke(propagation.kt:81)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext$runAsCoroutine$1.invoke(propagation.kt:81)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext.runAsCoroutine(propagation.kt:86)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext.runAsCoroutine(propagation.kt:81)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$launchTask$18(ProgressRunner.java:464)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.ConnectException: Could not connect to server /172.29.189.138:45279. Tried addresses: [/172.29.189.138].
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:67)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.GradleServerRunner$GradleServerEventsListener.doRun(GradleServerRunner.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.GradleServerRunner$GradleServerEventsListener.start$lambda$1(GradleServerRunner.kt:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:249)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextCallable.call(ContextCallable.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:27)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishTimedConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:1145)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.blockingConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:1183)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.tryConnect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:54)
    ... 14 more
2024-03-25 19:20:25,690 [1906424]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.s.e.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line to Gradle Tooling API: --init-script C:\Users\Rom\AppData\Local\Temp\ijIdeaPluginConfigurator1.gradle --init-script C:\Users\Rom\AppData\Local\Temp\ijMapper1.gradle -Didea.gradle.download.sources=false -Didea.sync.active=true -Didea.resolveSourceSetDependencies=true -Porg.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.cid=2604524552700 -Pkotlin.mpp.enableIntransitiveMetadataConfiguration=true --init-script C:\Users\Rom\AppData\Local\Temp\ijInit2.gradle -Didea.active=true -Didea.version=2023.3.6 -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains
2024-03-25 19:20:41,682 [1922416]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.s.p.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not connect to server /172.29.189.138:36009. Tried addresses: [/172.29.189.138].
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.GradleServerRunner$GradleServerEventsListener.start$lambda$1(GradleServerRunner.kt:179)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:249)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextCallable.call(ContextCallable.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:27)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.ConnectException: Could not connect to server /172.29.189.138:36009. Tried addresses: [/172.29.189.138].
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:67)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.GradleServerRunner$GradleServerEventsListener.doRun(GradleServerRunner.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.target.GradleServerRunner$GradleServerEventsListener.start$lambda$1(GradleServerRunner.kt:176)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishTimedConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:1145)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.blockingConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:1183)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.tryConnect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:54)
    ... 14 more
2024-03-25 19:20:41,687 [1922421]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/ivan/.jdks/corretto-21.0.2
2024-03-25 19:20:41,698 [1922432]   INFO - #o.j.k.i.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] IllegalStateException loading gradle script templates: Unable to get Gradle home directory
2024-03-25 19:20:41,699 [1922433]   INFO - #o.j.k.i.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] Cannot find valid gradle home with version = null, script models cannot be saved
2024-03-25 19:20:41,700 [1922434]   INFO - #c.i.o.e.u.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [//wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/ivan/spring-example] resolution task executed in 32076 ms.
2024-03-25 19:20:42,003 [1922737]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2024-03-25 19:20:42,042 [1922776]   INFO - #c.i.o.e.s.p.m.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 4 ms
2024-03-25 19:20:47,659 [1928393]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2024-03-25 19:20:51,493 [1932227]   INFO - #c.i.a.d.c.d.SqliteLazyInitializedDatabase - Database path: C:\Users\Rom\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJ\ae_e3b9fc46-1884-4d72-bece-98fc85c31de7-233.db
```

judging by the description, the problem is that there is no connection at the address 172.29.189.138:45279 and there is a recommendation to change it to 172.29.189.138, can someone tell me how to do this, I use WSL Ubuntu

Comment: Additional Information. Java has stopped working with existing projects (which were created earlier and worked perfectly), and when creating new ones, the same problem occurs. In other projects that were launched via the command line (gradl), for example my web project using Javelin, everything works fine via gradl. please help

Comment: Check the logs for more details: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085. Search https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA for similar issues. If it doesn't help, file a new bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with your logs attached.

Comment: I added the logs to the original question, please look, the problem is that there is no connection to 172.29.189.138:45279, how can I change the address to 172.29.189.138?

Comment: Try to disable Windows Firewall and see if it helps.

Comment: no, same error, just change in port address
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not connect to server /172.29.189.138:36131. Tried addresses: [/172.29.189.138].

Comment: Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-288191/WSL-Cant-load-gradle-dependencies. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html. There may be some problem with your WSL networking that is unrelated to IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle.